# Solr suffix/prefix search for numbers

Tags: apache, search, solr, prefix

Hlo,

I've one string which contains some data. I Am applying the ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory.

When i am using string, i am able to analyze the string matching. But when i use number i am not able to achieve the same.

It's not even searchable.

Following are the screenshots for the field schema, working example and non working( ie.Numbers Example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
  <field name="rcp" type="text_suffix" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <fieldType name="text_suffix" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`LowerCaseTokenizerFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory) removes anything that is not regular letters:

> Creates tokens by lowercasing all letters and dropping non-letters.

You might want to use [`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory), [`StandardTokenizerFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory) or [`ClassicTokenizerFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory) instead.

Comment: Then he can add a LowerCaseFilterFactory